# Tikz-qtree strange placement problem

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm having issues with the placement of the values in my tree, i'm not quite sure whats the cause of it. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}\hline
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \Tree[.1 [.5 ][.2 ][.1 ]]
    \caption{i=1, (Q = \{5, 2\})}
  \end{subfigure} &
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \Tree[.1 [.5 [.5 ][.6 ][.5 ]][.2 ][.1 ]]
    \caption{i=2, (Q = \{2, 6\})}
  \end{subfigure} \\\hline
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \Tree[.1 [.5 [.5 ][.6 ][.5 ]][.2 ][.1 ]]
    \caption{i=3, (Q = \{6, 4\})}
  \end{subfigure} &
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \Tree[.1 [.5 [.5 ][.6 [.8(GOAL) ]][.5 ]][.2 [.4 ][.2 ][.1 ]][.1 ]]
    \caption{i=4, (Q = \{4\})}
  \end{subfigure} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{BFS S,R,L}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works just fine over here, are you sure you have installed all packages? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Note that xdvi is not generally able to display properly TikZ pictures. Why aren't you using `pdflatex`?